# Generating a list with fixed length

Tags: r, list, deque

I need to generate a fixed-length list so that when the length is exceeded, the earliest item entered the list is dropped. This can be achieved by using `deque` (list-like container with fast appends and pops on either end) in Python.

I was wondering whether there is an R equivalent of python's `deque` ?

I know about `dequer` and `rstackdeque` libraries but none of them provide a fixed length queue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions requesting a function analogous to one in a different langauge are likelly to be closed as off topic. You would do better by explaining what "python's `deque`" does and what you have tried so far to replicate that functionality.

Comment: A `list` with fixed length 10 is produced by `list <- vector("list", 10)`. Perhaps this will lead to a function you can write by your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is the best way to do it but based on the comment by @J_F, I wrote the following function:

```
List <- vector("list", Length)

deque <- function(List, x)
{
  Length = length(List)
  List <- c(List, x)
  if (length(List) > Length)
  {
    List[1] <- NULL
  }
  return(List)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but r has an iterface to MongoDB, which has capped collections.  You might want to look into that.